# coremltools: output has no shape and cannot be used in pipeline -- how to fix it?

Tags: python, coremltools

When I convert tensorflow.keras models to CoreML using coremltools, my models end up having no output shape. I.e., if `model` is my `coremltools.models.MLModel` instance, `model.get_spec().description.output[0]` results in

> name: "output"
> shortDescription: "model output"
> type {
> multiArrayType {
> dataType: FLOAT32
> }
> }

so I have a multiArray with no specified output shape. This is fine and I can use it in my Xcode project. However, if I'm using `coremltols.models.pipeline.Pipeline` to combine two instances of `coremltools.models.Model`, I get the following message displayed when opening the model with Xcode:

> validator error: Pipeline: the input 'input' of model '...' does not match the type previously specified by the pipeline input or the output of a previous model. For the second case, make sure the input and previous model's output has the matching name and shape.

I checked that name and dataType coincide so the only thing I can think of is that the missing output shape is the issue. Unfortunately, I could not find a way to make coreml output the model's output shape.

Any ideas on this? Maybe there is some misuse of mine of the pipeline class?

Comment: Any luck solving this problem ?

Comment: @user1470618 unfortunately not. I ended up using two models in my application which at least is a workaround bypassing the problem. If you can figure out how to solve the problem (ie how to use a pipeline), please let me know.

Comment: I did I used :1. https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1gDZ2xcTOgR39tGGs-EZ6i3RTs16wmzZQ to train my model 2. Created an enivornment for yolov5 project and cloned the project, 3. patched this https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/pull/7263. used export and I got it to work.